# Angular Http Not working. Promise mixed with Observable approach

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular2-services

I'm trying to post the data to backend Node js file from Angular. After form **submit** below function is called:

```
cmdSubmit() : void 
{
       console.log(this.cli);
       this.Cliservice.postdata(this.cli)
                      .then(clidata  => this.clidata.push(clidata),
                            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

}
```

postdata function code:

```
postdata(obj: any): Promise<any> {
    alert('hello');
    let body = JSON.stringify({ obj });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.runUrl, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);

    /*return this.http.post(this.runUrl, body, options)
                      .map(this.extractData)
                      .catch(res => {
             // do something

             // To throw another error, use Observable.throw
             return Observable.throw(res.json());
      });*/


    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
       let body = res.json();
       return body.data || { };
    }

private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                  error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
 }

}
```

But nothing is happening here. I do not get any error message. Can you please suggest anything on this?

Answer (score 9):

Every `Http` function which returns `Observable` must have a `.subscribe()` method attached to it. When you miss this method the request will not executed. So attach `.subscribe()` method to each function.

As was been said in the comments, you are using two approaches: `Promise style` and `Observable style`, so I advice you to use one common style.

```
this.http.post(this.runUrl, body, options)
         .map(this.extractData).subscribe(/*here your parameters*/);
```

Comment: He is also mixing up `Observable` and `Promise`, without converting to a `Promise`.

Comment: @rinukkusu Yes, he need to use a common style

Comment: Just telling you that so you can improve your answer a little to address all his errors :)

Answer (score 3):

What @Suren mentioned is perfectly correct. As an alternative, you can also use the `toPromise()` method on this as well to directly convert it to a Promise object:

```
return this.http.post(this.runUrl, body, options).toPromise();
```

For this, you need to import the following

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'
```